# I can't draw to a JPanel

Tags: java

I am trying to use JPanel to draw to a window, but nothing shows up.

I've tried looking online, but I couldn't find anything.

```
    private void initialize()
{
    _frame = new JFrame(_name);
    _panel = new JPanel();


    _frame.setSize(_scaledSize);
    _frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    _frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    _frame.setResizable(true);

    _panel.setPreferredSize(_scaledSize);
    _panel.setMinimumSize(_scaledSize);
    _panel.setMaximumSize(_scaledSize);

    _frame.getContentPane().add(_panel);


    _frame.pack();


    _frame.setVisible(true);
}

public JPanel getPanel()
{
    return _panel;
}
```

Method that is responible for drawing

```
  public void draw()
{
    Graphics graphics;
    graphics = _display.getPanel().getGraphics();
    graphics.setColor(Color.black);
    graphics.drawRect(20, 20, 100, 100);
}
```

It shows a blank screen... nothing is drawn.

Comment: Side note: Do yourself a favor and ditch that leading underscore in your variable and field names (so `panel` instead of `_panel`) . That will make it easier to read for you and us.

Comment: We'd need to see a [mcve]. Do you call `initialize()`? Where is `draw()` being called?

Comment: try `graphics = _panel.getGraphics();` in `public void draw()` method instead

Comment: What's `_display`? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: @Benas **Never** do that.  getGraphics() does not return a Graphics object that will draw to the component!  The only correct way to draw on a JPanel is by overriding its [paintComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

To draw to a JPanel set its layout to null  `_panel.setLayout(null);` (If you want to add multiple shapes).Set it to `_panel.setLayout(new CardLayout` (if you want to add Only 1 Shape).

Hence Your main method will becomes    ***NB  `Shape` is the panel that we are going to draw**

```
    Shape shape = new Shape();
    shape.setSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
    shape.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
   _panel.add(shape).setLocation(0, 0);
```

Shape code will then become

```
class Shape extends JPanel {
public GeneralPath getShape() {
    GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
    path.moveTo(20, 20);
    path.lineTo(20, 40);
    path.lineTo(40,40);
    path.lineTo(40,20);
    path.closePath();
    return path;
}
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    GeneralPath pt = getShape();
    g2d.scale(2, 2);
    g2d.draw(pt);
   }
  }
```

[image: Sample output]